# How to select max and min value of any column of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a datagridview control on my windows form.
Now i need to select max and min value of a column.
In data-table we can do this by using this

### Code

```
int maxID = curriculmDataTable.AsEnumerable().Max(r => r.Field<int>("Id"));
```

How can i achieve this in datagridview.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try:

```
var MaxID = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["Id"].Value));
```

Make sure your `Id` cell has `int` type value, otherwise use `Int.TryParse` like:

```
int temp;
var MaxID2 = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Max(r => int.TryParse(r.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString(), out temp) ? 
                       temp : 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your datasource is a datatable this sample can help you.

```
DataTable dtDataSource = new DataTable();

dtDataSource.Columns.Add("Value");
dtDataSource.Columns.Add("Display");

dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1});
dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2 });
dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 3 });
dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 4 });
dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 5 });

var results = dtDataSource.AsEnumerable().Max(row => Convert.ToInt32(row["Value"]));
```

Comment: No i am not using any kind of datasource.
I am using DataGridView.Rows.Add() for adding rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable dt=datagridview1.datasource as datatable
int total = dt.Compute("Sum ( ColumnName ) ", "Criteria");
```

Comment: Code only answers are usually [frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding an [explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.