# How to find out Minimum & maximum Date from a datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` in which a row conatins dates and I want to find min & max value from that row.

How can i get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select max and min value of any column of datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558212/how-to-select-max-and-min-value-of-any-column-of-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

You could use help of collections:

```
// select row with index that you want (I used 0 for example)
var row = dataGridView1.Rows[0];
List<DateTime> datesInRow = new List<DateTime>();
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
  datesInRow.Add((DateTime)cell.Value);
var maxDate = datesInRow.Max();
```

Of course, more efficient way would be finding max manually, then you wouldn't need extra collection to do it for you :)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Hm, I don't see any method like `Max` for `DataGridViewCellsColection`... Since cell can hold any object, how you would even expect it to work?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd That is why it isn't so obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

in my estimation, using linq methods. Because short and basic code.

```
var dateTimes = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            //.Select(x => (DateTime) x.Cells["ColumnName"].Value); //if column type datetime
            //or    
            .Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Cells["ColumnName"].Value));

var minValue = dateTimes.Min();
var maxValue = dateTimes.Max();
```