# How to find maximum value from datagridview and display them? and how to label the maximum value on the graph in c#?

Tags: c#, graph, max

I am a really beginner in c#, all this code I just follow tutorial from youtube but now i dont find any tutorial on how to find the maximum value from datagridview and label them on the graph. PLease help me by share the code.

[This is what i want, the data is on the left. i want to the display the max. value and the label it on the graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saRxl.jpg)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table.Columns.Add("X Pos (mm)", typeof(double));
        table.Columns.Add("Power (mWs)", typeof(double));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

    }

    private void button1_openfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Siti Nurhazwani\Desktop\table.txt");
        string[] values;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            values = lines[i].ToString().Split('/');
            string[] row = new string[values.Length];

            for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
            {
                row[j] = values[j].Trim();
            }

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    private void button2_visualize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var chart = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
        chart.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

        chart.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "";
        chart.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "";
        chart.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;

        int rowcount = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
        double c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < rowcount; i++)
        {
            c1 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            c2 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            chart1.Series["Signal"].Points.AddXY(c1, c2);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

have you seen https://1bestcsharp.blogspot.com/2016/04/csharp-datagridview-maximum-column-value.html ?
I wish you much success and patience :D

Convert Options:
1 (Step by Step);

```
// Convert String Array into double[]
 double[] xs = Array.ConvertAll(c0, double.Parse);
```

```
2(for loop);

*your_variable*.Add(Array.ConvertAll(DataSeries[i], double.Parse));
```

Comment: Sir, I already refer to this website, but seem it have some errors occur. I dont know how to solve the problem. In my datagridview i dont have the max. values box. How to add them?

Comment: you can search for min, max Value in a Column on your Datagridview like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558212/how-to-select-max-and-min-value-of-any-column-of-datagridview). The Problem is you convert your Data into a string, so logically you cannot search for min and max. 
You can Label anything on Charts with "Annotations". (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: sir i am really sorry sir but still i dont get it. can i just change the data from string into double? i tried but error.  I have try follow this tutorial on youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmZGzUcA50A) , but i dont have the max box on the early start. really appreciate your help thank you so much :)